# Que diferencia hay entre bean staleful y staless?

Tags: java, ejb

¿Que diferencia hay entre un EJB staleful y staless? Las categorías para los sessionBeans, pero ¿cuál sería la diferencia concreta?

Comment: A lo mejor quieres decir _stateful_ y _stateless_... literalmente _con estado_ y _sin estado_. La diferencia es que una tiene/guarda el estado y la otra no...

Comment: @toledano sí y no. En realidad se refiere a 2 de los 3 tipos de EJB. Mientras que la diferencia parece ser sutil, también hay unas diferencias que manejan los servidores JEE sobre estos beans.

Answer (score 1):

Un EJB stateless o sin estado, es una EJB que no guarda ninguna informacion en su instancia, por ende una peticion a un EJB de este tipo solamente usara los datos que se pasen como parametro y los datos que en el calculo se obtengan de diferentes fuentes de datos, pero nunca va a guardar informacion en variables en memoria para consulta posterior, ya que cuando se vuelve a invocar la funcion del EJB stateless, el Servidor de aplicaciones va a devolver una instancia diferente de EJB, no dando sentido a guardar variables en memoria ya que se van a perder. Perfecto para operaciones transaccionales que se resuelven dentro de la misma peticion.

Un EJB Stateful, es un ejb con estado es decir puedes mantener datos en memoria para posterior consulta, perfecto para por ejemplo un carro de compras, aunque hay que usarlos con cuidado por que mantener un stateful afecta directamente la memoria

Cualquier cosa quedo atento

Comment: muchas gracias, podrias indicarnos en que literatura se puede profundizar este tema?

Comment: Aqui esta la informacion completa http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html